# Object target radius checking in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an attacking sword thing that moves between 3 points. The main place in the characters hand, the top of the swing and the bottom of the swing. After that it goes back to the hand.

I used the general "ground check for jumping" code and modified it a bit because using "Move towards" in a loop never quite hit exactly for changing to the next stage.

Both errors are on the "reachedTarget" line;

```
The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Physics2D.OverlapCircle(UnityEngine.Vector2, float, int)' has some invalid arguments

Argument `#3' cannot convert `UnityEngine.Vector3' expression to type `int'
```

Here's the code.

```
void TargetCheck(GameObject target)
{
    //Returns true when the sword is over the target
    reachedTarget = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, 0.1f, target.transform.position);
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: target.transform.position is not an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"cannot convert x expression to type y" always means you're trying to enter something of type x where you need type y. For instance: int number = "hello world"; will not work. You're trying to convert int to string

In your case you're trying to enter an `int LayerMask` with `target.transform.position`. [See documentation on OverlapCircle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html)

If you're not sure about which LayerMasks and how to bitshift, declare a `public LayerMask layermask;` and let Unity serialize it. This will give you checkbox buttons to fill in which Layers.

Edit: it appears `Vector3.Distance` was what OP wanted!

Comment: Ah, thanks. So I can't do it like this then. How else can I see if one object is near enough to the other. I had `if (sword.transform.position == target.transform.position)` but it never quite hit perfectly, is there any way to add a radius to this?

Comment: You can shoot Raycasts and look at their length/target hit or add Colliders and check when they collide! It's a 2D-game right?

Comment: Yes, 2D game. I've got no idea how to do Raycasts but I'll look it up and give it a go. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I've tried using a raycast, but is there a way to do "From vector to vector"? I have to give it a direction and I can't figure out how to do that. I've seen some people talking about "Linecasts" but they don't have a range to return true from. The "Debug.DrawLine" function is a linecast not a raycast it seems. That goes from vector to vector but raycast doesn't.

Is there any way to either make the Raycast from vector to vector or the linecast have a length to check on rather than "Can it be seen or is there an object before"

Comment: Distance from vector to vector? Sounds like Vector3.Distance! https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html

Comment: So what you want is `if (Vector3.Distance(object1, object2)  < minDistance) { /*do something because they're too close to each other*/ }`

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll make this the ticked answer :) Could you add that last bit of distance code to your answer so people looking for the same thing can see :) Thanks :)

Comment: Sure thing! Updated!

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont need the third parameter. That should be the layer of whose Objects you want to collide with. Make sure it's the layer id of your target.

Afterwards reachedTarget should probably be compared with target's Collider2D component. If it matches - you've got a hit.

**Edit for lazy people - should be something like:**

```
void TargetCheck(GameObject target)
{
    //Returns true when the sword is over the target
    var CollidedWith = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, 0.1f, *LayerYouWantToCollideWith*);

    var TargetCollider2D = target.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    bool CollidedWithTarget = CollidedWith == TargetCollider2D;
}
```

PS: you should probably get the Collider2D component of your target beforehand and store it somewhere..